# Can __rrshift__ take more than one argument?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to overload the `__rrshift__` method on one class. The basic implementation follows:

```
class A:
    def __rrshift__(self, arg0):
        print(f'called A.__rrshift__ with arg0={arg0}')

a = A()
42 >> a
```

Here I got the expected result:

```
called A.__rrshift__ with arg0=42
```

But if I call this method with more than one argument, only the last one is used:

```
'hello', 'world' >> a
```

Which returns:

```
called A.__rrshift__ with arg0=world
```

If I try and add arguments to the `__rrshift__` method, the behavior is not modified as I expected:

```
class B:
    def __rrshift__(self, arg0, arg1=None):
        print(f'called B.__rrshift__ with arg0={arg0}, arg1={arg1}')

b = B()
42 >> b
'hello', 'world' >> b

# called B.__rrshift__ with arg0=42, arg1=None
# called B.__rrshift__ with arg0=world, arg1=None
```

Is it possible to consider more than one argument for the `__rrshift__` method?

Comment: A (temporary?) solution I found is to accept only one argument, that can be a single value or a tuple, and process them in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible.

`__rrshift__`, like `__add__`, `__sub__` et al. are *binary operators*. They accept exactly two arguments: `self` and `whatever_other_argument`.

Of course, you can cheat the system by calling these methods explicitly, and then they'll be able to accept as many arguments as you want, but if you use the operators like `>>`, `+`, `-` et al., then the syntax of the language will force them to accept two arguments exactly.

You can probably modify that by hacking the heck of Python's grammar with the `ast` module, but that won't be Python anymore.

Here's how `a, b >> c` is seen by the Python parser, according to [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html):

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('a, b >> c'))
# I prettified this myself. The actual output of `dump` is horrendous looking.
Module(
 body=[
  Expr(
   # Build a tuple...
   value=Tuple(elts=[
    Name(id='a', ctx=Load()), # ...containing `a`...
    # ...and the result of a BINARY OPERATOR (RShift)...
    BinOp(
     left=Name(id='b', ctx=Load()), # ...which is applied to `b`...
     op=RShift(),
     right=Name(id='c', ctx=Load()) # ...and `c`
    )
    ],
    ctx=Load()
   )
  )
  ]
 )
```

The production in the grammar that produces [sic] the tuple seems to be the following:

```
testlist_star_expr: (test|star_expr) (',' (test|star_expr))* [',']
```

As you can see, it then goes on to parser the `test` production, which is then unpacked all the way to the `expr` production, which then arrives at the following production:

```
shift_expr: arith_expr (('<<'|'>>') arith_expr)*
```

So, the first `test` in `testlist_star_expr` resolves to `atom: NAME`, and the second one - to `shift_expr`. This later ends up constructing the tuple.

Comment: That was my feeling as well. The point I am missing is: why has the tuple packing/unpacking a lower operator priority than `>>`? I cannot find any reference to justify that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are after but if you just need to supply some args (kwargs eventually), this might show you how to achieve that:

```
class A:
    def __rrshift__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            print(f'called A.__rrshift__ with arg={", ".join(args)}')
        else:
            print(f'called A.__rrshift__ with arg={args[0]}')

a = A()
a.__rrshift__('hello', 'world')
a.__rrshift__(42)

#called A.__rrshift__ with arg=hello, world
#called A.__rrshift__ with arg=42
```

Comment: Thx. That is what I ended up with. The only point is it forces me to explicitly create a tuple to pass two arguments: ('hello', 'world') >> a